# The select statement includes a reserved word c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, ms-access

i have problem in my c# application, it was used MYSQL database and no problem where !, but when i change the database to MS access this problem appear:
The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect.

and this is my code:

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT action.info, relation.id AS action FROM relation LEFT OUTER JOIN conditions ON relation.conditions_id = conditions.id LEFT OUTER JOIN situation ON relation.situation_id = situation.id LEFT OUTER JOIN car_type ON relation.car_id = car_type.id LEFT OUTER JOIN action ON relation.action_id = action.id LEFT OUTER JOIN signal AS signaal1 ON relation.signal_id = signaal1.id where car_type.info=@car_type" + string2 + "  ORDER BY conditions.id ASC", objConn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@car_type", radButton1.Text);

            OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

the error appear when last line executed..! "OleDbDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();"

-------------------------------------EDITED
I changed tables names by adding 'z' to tables names, and now another message appear:

[image]

Comment: "action" is a reserved word.  You need to place brackets around it [action] or use another name for that item.

Comment: @KingOfAllTrades: Action is not in the [list of reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)?

Comment: @GrantWinney: Access would not allow multiple left joins either?  I seem to remember it requires parenthesis around consecutive joins.

Comment: `action` is reserved in t-sql.  Something with triggers.  I agree it is not on either of those lists, but it will highlight in blue in SSMS.  While OP is using MS-Access, I would remove all MS related SQL reserved words.

Comment: I would never use the same name (reserved word or not) both as an alias for a field expression and as a table name.  The query above includes `SELECT relation.id AS action` and later `LEFT OUTER JOIN action`.  Not claiming that contributes to the error, but it just seems wrong to me.  :-(

Comment: @HansUp I agree, and would add that words like `relation`, `condition`, and `action` always be avoided in SQL.  I try to make all my aliases something readable but not an actual word.  I would use `rels`, `cond` or `thisaction`.

Comment: Just seconding Andomar's statement that MSAccess requires parenthesis around consecutive joins. Of the form `FROM (((a LJ B) LJ c) LJ d)`

Comment: What is the value of `string2`?  That could be a sql injection vulnerability.

Comment: I don't think that are reserved words ! because they was work in MYSQL !

Comment: This is value of string2:
string string2 = "";
                if (radButton2 != null)
                {
                    string2 = " and signaal1.info='" + radButton2.Text + "' ";
                }
                else
                    string2 = " and signaal1.info='0' ";
                if (radButton3 != null)
                {
                    string2 += " and situation.info='" + radButton3.Text + "' ";
                }

Comment: @user3763770, you said: "I don't think that are reserved words ! because they was work in MYSQL !".  But different sql engines can work differently.  So just because something worked in MySql does not mean it will work in another engine.

Comment: try SELECT action.info, relation.id AS action FROM
 ((((relation LEFT OUTER JOIN conditions ON relation.conditions_id = conditions.id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN situation ON relation.situation_id = situation.id) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN car_type ON relation.car_id = car_type.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN action ON relation.action_id = action.id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN signal AS signaal1 ON relation.signal_id = signaal1.id

Comment: The select statement includes a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

Thanx  @Grant_Winney, i changed action and relation, the error disappear :D but another one appear :s ( i asked another question)